# How to find derivative with respect to vectorized variable in R

Tags: r, math, derivative

I have the following function in R with which I can easily find its partial derivative with respect to x1 or x2 or x3:

```
ppp <- function(x1,x2, x3, m)  { 
n*log(m[1]*exp(x1) + m[2]*exp(x2) + m[3]*exp(x3) + m[4]) 
}
Deriv(ppp, "x3")
```

How can I automate the function so that I would find the derivative as `Deriv(ppp, "x[3]")`?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
ppp <- function(x, m)  { 
n*log(m[1]*exp(x[1]) + m[2]*exp(x[2]) + m[3]*exp(x[3]) + m[4]) 
}
Deriv(ppp, "x[1]")
```

Is there a way I could rewrite the function with `sum()` considering that `m[1]*exp(x[1]) + m[2]*exp(x[2]) + m[3]*exp(x[3])` ranges from 1 to 3 for both the parameters of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a wrapper around `Deriv` which converts subscripts to variables and back again:

```r
library(Deriv)

Deriv_vec <- function(f, var, ...)
{
  bod <- c(gsub(var, "new_var", as.character(body(f)), fixed = TRUE), "}")
  body(f) <- parse(text = bod)
  formals(f) <- c(alist(new_var=), formals(f))
  result <- Deriv(f, "new_var", ...)

  bod <- c(gsub("new_var", var, as.character(body(result)), fixed = TRUE), "}")
  body(result) <- parse(text = bod)
  formals(result) <- formals(result)[-1]
  result
}
```

This allows:

```r
ppp <- function(x, m)  { 
   n*log(m[1] * exp(x[1]) + m[2] * exp(x[2]) + m[3] * exp(x[3]) + m[4]) 
}

Deriv_vec(ppp, "x[1]")
#> function (x, m) 
#> {
#>     .e1 <- exp(x[1])
#>     n * .e1 * m[1]/(.e1 * m[1] + exp(x[2]) * m[2] + exp(x[3]) * 
#>         m[3] + m[4])
#> }

Deriv_vec(ppp, "x[3]")
#> function (x, m) 
#> {
#>     .e1 <- exp(x[3])
#>     n * .e1 * m[3]/(.e1 * m[3] + exp(x[1]) * m[1] + exp(x[2]) * 
#>         m[2] + m[4])
#> }
```

If you need a version that takes multiple variables, this is more complex, but could be achieved like this:

```r
Deriv_vec <- function(f, var, ...)
{
  for(i in seq_along(var)) {
    bod <- c(gsub(var[i], 
                  paste0("new_var", i),
                  as.character(body(f)), fixed = TRUE), "}")
    body(f) <- parse(text = bod)
  }
  
  new_vars <- paste0("new_var", seq_along(var))
  new_args <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(new_vars), 
                              function(x) alist(a=)$a), new_vars)
  formals(f) <- c(new_args, formals(f))
  
  result <- Deriv(f, new_vars, ...)
  
  for(i in seq_along(var))
  {
    bod <- c(gsub(new_vars[i], var[i], 
                  as.character(body(result)), fixed = TRUE), "}")
    if(substr(bod[length(bod) - 1], 1, 2) == "c(")
    {
      bod[length(bod) - 1] <- 
        gsub(var[i], paste0("`", var[i], "`"), bod[length(bod) - 1],
             fixed = TRUE)
    }
    body(result) <- parse(text = bod)
  }
  formals(result) <- formals(result)[-seq_along(var)]
  result
}
```

This then allows:

```
Deriv_vec(ppp, c("x[1]", "x[2]", "x[3]"))
#> function (x, m) 
#> {
#>     .e1 <- exp(x[1])
#>     .e2 <- exp(x[2])
#>     .e3 <- exp(x[3])
#>     .e7 <- .e1 * m[1] + .e2 * m[2] + .e3 * m[3] + m[4]
#>     c(`x[1]` = n * .e1 * m[1]/.e7, `x[2]` = n * .e2 * 
#>         m[2]/.e7, `x[3]` = n * .e3 * m[3]/.e7)
#> }
```

Just be careful with your specific example. The function `ppp` contains a variable called `n`. This should probably be included as a parameter.

Comment: This is really great but how can I pass a function with more than one variable. This is what I mean Deriv_vec(ppp, c("x[1]","x[2]")). I am thinking of it in a general form because I may even want to call more than two variable. In other words how would I pass the pattern argument in gsub() as a vector and not of length 1.

Comment: @Muhamd the problem with this is that if you pass more than one variable to `Deriv`, it returns a named vector. This is named according to the variables used, but `x[1]` and `x[2]` are not legal names in R, so you can no longer use gsub trick alone. It will take a bit more work to get this functioning as expected

Comment: @Muhamd see my edit. And please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for advice on what to do next if someone answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way I would call the first functional output (the function that calls only "x[1]") using a matrix (illustration below). I am thinking of a multidimensional problem and using `Deriv` with a matrix too looks a little complicated. This is what I mean: `x[1]` could be `x[,1]`. With the call derivative being `DD= Deriv_vec(ppp, "x[,1]")` Then I would want to make such a call `DD(x=cbind(c(1.3, 1.6, 2.7),c(1.1, 1.2, 1)), m = c(0.1,0.2,0.8))`, `n` is a constant and I could change it within the function. I can imagine the big problem would be the `Deriv`. Any way around it?

Comment: @Muhamd this would still work, but obviously you would have to change `ppp` so that instead of `x[1]`, `x[2]` etc, you would need `x[, 1]`, `x[, 2]` etc. You also need to make sure you pass the variable with a space after the comma, so `"x[, 1]"`, not `"x[,1]"`